# rviz configuration file format

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the rviz wiki, one of the command line arguments is listed as :

```
-d, --display-config <arg>

Load configuration file <arg> at startup.
```

What is the format for rviz configuration files, to feed rviz at the command line?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11845/rviz-configuration-file-format/) by [j-v](https://answers.ros.org/users/1329/j-v/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to edit rviz configurations is through rviz itself:

- Open rviz and set up whatever displays and layout you like.
- Go to File->Save Config and choose a descriptive file name.

Later, you can restore your configuration by running rviz with `-d`, or with File->Open Config. rviz also maintains a list of File->Recent Configs for you. Saving your config is useful when you have a specific desired layout for an application or demo.

For day-to-day use, rviz stores your current config in `$HOME/.rviz/display_config`, so you can close and re-open rviz without losing your displays and layout.

In general there's no need to edit .vcg files by hand, but they are in a simple [INI format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). Save one out and open it in your favorite text editor to see the details.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10